PyQt6 combobox weird black bars on top and bottom sides
I tried almost everything (Adjusting heights, removing paddings) but can't get this black bar get removed from combobox.

Stylesheet I am currently using
QComboBox {
    border: 2px solid #AD86FF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px; 
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0px; 
}

QComboBox::drop-down {
    subcontrol-position: center right;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-left-color: #AD86FF;
    border-left-style: solid;
    background-color: #fff; 
    padding: 6px; 
    margin: 0px; 
    border-radius: 0px; 
}

QComboBox::drop-down::indicator {
    image: url(./assets/dropdown.png);
    width: 16px; 
    height: 16px; 
    background: transparent;
}

QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    border: 2px solid #AD86FF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    selection-background-color: #8F6ED4;
    selection-color: white;
    background-color: #fff; 
    alternate-background-color: #f0f0f0;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #333;
    padding: 0px; 
    margin: 0px; 
    spacing: 0px;
}

QComboBox::item {
    height: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px; 
    padding-right: 10px; 
}

QComboBox::item:selected {
    background-color: #8F6ED4;
    color: white;
}

QComboBox::item:hover {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}


I am thinking this issue is not from qt itself but from my window manager, gnome (wayland). Your thoughts? How I can fix something weird as is.
I tried out different padding, heights, margins (even resetting all custom style). The black bar still appears.

Are you sure that there are not other style sheets in play (possibly set on a parent widget, or even the QApplication)? Did you try it with a basic test that only has the combo box and the style sheet above? What is the result of QApplication.style().objectName()? If it's not "fusion", then try it, and also consider testing all the other results of QStyleFactory.keys().

I fixed it setting other way around, QApplication.style() is already set to fusion. I set it to windows and it seems to fixed for now. I will look deeper into it (later).
Thanks for guiding me into right path.

Ok, but the fact that the fusion style gives that result is quite important, as it's considered the reference style, especially when dealing with QSS: the expectation is that using the "fusion" QSyle should always be consistently reliable, if something doesn't work with it its very important to know about it. I didn't have the opportunity to thoroughly check your QSS, so I strongly suggest you to do some further testing with different selector/property combinations, possibly checking against a non-wayland environment. Eventually update this post or consider filing https://bugreports.qt.io.

Yet, consider what suggested above: ensure that no other inherited QSS exists. I don't fully remember the QSS implementation, as it's quite complex: it's a private QStyle that is automatically set on any widget that may be affected by stylesheets, even indirectly (including the possibility of children using QSS on their own, even if the widget itself is not affected). It also often uses the "windows" style indirectly as a fallback, even if that may seem unexpected. The "Wayland variable" is also an important aspect, so it's really important that you check the basic X11 alternative.
